# Violating the Lebesgue density theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measure-concentration

Can anyone exhibit a finite-dimensional metric space (preferably, $R^d$) equipped with a measure that does not satisfy the conclusions of the Lebesgue Density Theorem? Such examples exist in infinite-dimensional spaces (e.g., Hilbert space with the Gaussian measure) but what about a finite-dimensional one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a theorem of Besicovitch that measures on $\mathbb R^d$ do satisfy the density theorem.

> [image: picture]
>   Fremlin, *Measure Theory*, [Chap. 47](https://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/cont47.htm)

**added**

> Besicovitch, around 1930, extended his density properties of sets to those of finite Hausdorff measure.
>   [source](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Besicovitch.html)

next: D. G. Larman, "A new theory of dimension", *Proc. London. Math. Soc.* **17** (1967) 178-192

> Def: a metric space is *finite-dimensional in the sense of Larman* iff there is a constant $K$ such that every ball of radius $2R$ can be covered by at most $K$ balls of radius $R$.

Larman proves that such finite-dimensional spaces have a Vitali-type property, which of course implies the density theorem for all measures.  (Lebesgue's and Besicovitch's proofs used Vitali coverings.)

My student Manav Das investigated metric spaces with various Vitali-type properties.  For example:
*Nonlinear Anal.* **46** (2001) 457-463
*Real Analysis Exchange* **27** (2001/02) 7-15

Comment: Thanks, @Gerald! What about a more general (but still finite-dimensional) metric space?

Comment: Gerald, metric spaces with finite Larman dimension are what's called today "doubling metric spaces" (i.e., those with a finite doubling dimension), right? I know that any such space equipped with a doubling measure satisfies LDT, but Larman shows something stronger -- that it holds for *all* measures, even non-doubling ones -- correct?